# Find internal surface area of painted cube

Tags: geometry, surfaces

Suppose that a wooden cube, whose edge is $3$ inch, is painted red, then cut into $27$ pieces of $1$ inch edge. Find total surface area of unpainted?

First of all, I have tried to draw the cube using MS Paint, below is given picture:

[image]

The surface area of cube is $6\cdot a^2$, where $a$ is the length of cube, when cube is painted, I'm trying to imagine it visually, how much surface would be unpainted?

If it's painted,does not it mean that all pages are painted?

**EDIT:**

A $3\times3\times3$ cube gets painted red. Then it gets split into $27$, $1\times1\times1$ cubes.

Find the number of painted faces:

On the $3$ inch cube, there are $9$ $1$-inch faces on each face, and there are $6$ such faces, so the total red 1-inch faces is:
$$
9\cdot 6=54
$$
Find the total number of faces of all the cubes:

There are $6$ faces per cube and $27$ cubes, so:
$$
27\cdot 6=162.
$$
Of these, we know $54$ are painted:
$$
162-54=108
$$
There is a total of $108$ unpainted $1\times1$ squares each having an area of 1, so there are $108$ unpainted square inches.

**EDIT:**

I'd like to post also my approaches if the cube would be divided into *two identical parts*, actually if we have a cube with length $a$, divided into $2$  parts, then we get two cubes, which volume is $a^3/2$.

So length is the cubic root of $a^3/2$, or length of this two cubes is $a$ divided by cubic root of $2$.

Now we have length $3$, which means that it's length would be $3$ divided by cubic root of $2$, on each face with length $3$, we would have:
$$
\frac{9}{3/\sqrt[3]{2}}=3\cdot \sqrt[3]{2}
$$
in total $4$ such cubes, so  $2*4$ of such  faces, total face would be  $2*6=12$,so unpainted would be $12-8=4$ is it correct?

Comment: I'm sorry but if you consider the shape just being cut into two pieces, you are actually "morphing" the cube in order to obtain *two identical cubes*. This, in reality is impossible because from a cube two identical sub-cubes can not be generated by one slice.

Comment: so it means that we  only can cut cube  into several part,if it's volume is divided by number of cut and get cube with  exact number of length??

Comment: in your case we have divided by $27$,because volume of cube is $27$

Comment: Yes, but this works because if you re-attach every sub-cube you get back to the original one, and this works even with random slices, as @ Blue pointed out. But in your case you can not re-attach two identical cubes to form the original cube, because you modified the shape of the slices. In the other case we *didn't talked about dividing the volume* because this would modify the shape of the sub cubes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer requires some spatial examples, so I think it will be better if I generalize the case of a simple cube, which can be applied to all possible situations.

As you said, the total area covered by the paint in a cube with lenght $a$ is equal to:
$$
S_{\mathrm{ext}}=6\cdot a^2
$$
But then the division into $27$ cubes with lenght $1/3$ of the original gives the new surface area, greater than the original because new slices prodce more internal surface; so now the total surface is expressed by:
$$
S_{\mathrm{tot}}=27\cdot 6\cdot (a/3)^2=\frac{27\cdot 6}{9}\cdot a^2=3\cdot 6\cdot a^2=3S_{\mathrm{ext}}
$$
Now think about a Rubik's Cube, with only the cubes facing the outside are painted: since you know that the total amount of paint occupies the *external* surface $S_{\mathrm{ext}}$, then to know the surface *not* covered in paint you have to simply subtract to the total sliced surface $S_{\mathrm{tot}}$ the external one:
$$
S_{\mathrm{unpaint}}=S_{\mathrm{tot}}-S_{\mathrm{ext}}=3S_{\mathrm{ext}}-S_{\mathrm{ext}}=2S_{\mathrm{ext}}=12\cdot a^2
$$
Now you have basically derived the sum of the *internal* surface of every little cube, because the sum of the external is nothing more than the total covered in paint, or $S_{\mathrm{ext}}$ (with the Rubik's Cube case, the only cubes coloured).

**EDIT**: If *the number of slices* is not defined, it is generalized to a single parameter $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then the new surface tends to be greater as $n$ gets larger.

Let's assume that one cut is repeated on every edge of the cube, so if an edge is divided in three (*with two slices*), then the number of cubes created is expressed as follows:
$$
N_{\mathrm{cubes}}=(n+1)^3
$$
So if I "slice" a cube for every edge *once* ($n=1$), I get $N_{\mathrm{cubes}}=(2)^3=8$ little cubes.

The surface of *each sub-cube* is expressed by:
$$
S_{\mathrm{sub-cb}}=6\cdot\left(\frac{a}{n+1}\right)^2
$$
Then the total surface is expressed as th single one multiplied by the total number of sub-cubes created $N_{\mathrm{cubes}}$:
$$
S_{\mathrm{tot}}=(n+1)^3\cdot 6\cdot\left(\frac{a}{n+1}\right)^2=(n+1)\cdot 6\cdot a^2=(n+1)\cdot S_{\mathrm{ext}}
$$
Now, applying the same deduction as before, the surface not covered with paint is given by a simple subtraction between the total surface and the ponly painted one, which is the external one:
$$
S_{\mathrm{unpaint}}=S_{\mathrm{tot}}-S_{\mathrm{ext}}=(n+1)\cdot S_{\mathrm{ext}}-S_{\mathrm{ext}}=n\cdot S_{\mathrm{ext}}
$$
Now remember that the parameter $n$ is the number of slices, and not the sub-cubes created; as your previous example, the slices were $2$, and so this number appeared inside the final result.

Comment: what if figure is not cube?original or  new figure,for example cube is cutted  into $27$  rectangular  solid or something like this

Comment: Well, if the cuts are not regular, the inital equation is different and so the reasoning behind its derivation.

Comment: or for example instead of $27$,it is divided into half part?forumula would be same yes  or

Comment: @ giorgi If it is divided into $n$ parts (so $2$, $3$ ...), I'd like to explain a more genealized case. Mind if I edit the answer to add this new case?

Comment: ok i would be happy,thanks very much

Comment: Now this has been covered with a little bit of precision: if you notice as $n\to \infty$ the surface of a single cube is $S_{\mathrm{sub-cb}}\to 0$, with every possible $n$!

Comment: so for example if it is divided into  $2$ cube,then length of $3$ inch  cube  would be cubic root of  $13.5$?

Comment: If the lenght $a$ is three inches, dividing it by two means that I gave *one slice* ($n=1$). But I didn't understand the last part of your comment: "then lnegth of 3 inch cube would be cubic root of 13.5". I don't know what does it mean.

Comment: we have divided  $3$ inches   cube into $27$ part,so get $1$ inch cubes,if we divided  it into $2$ part,then what would be length o f cube?suppose we  were asked that  cube is divided into two part,find surface area of unpainted one

Comment: Numerically, the new lenght (which in my formula *does not appear because it simplifies*) is equal to $3/2$ Inches. In your case if you divide into two part you slice *once* ($n=1$), so the un-painted surface is: $1\cdot 6\cdot (3\:\mathrm{inch})^2=54\:\mathrm{inch}^2$

Comment: wait i am   confused now,when we divided into $27$ part,we see that  we have total $6$ face and  on each $3$ inch  face we have  $9$   1 inch faces,so total $9*6=54$,but if we divide it into  2 part instead of  27,why we have length   3/2?

Comment: That's the main problem, so I'm sorry for the previous comment; If you divide a cube into two parts **and not** $1,8,27...$ the equation **changes**, because I'm considering *a slice on each edge*.

Comment: i need generally for two,please could you update answer

Comment: If you want, I'll add another answer to specify yout case and no more confusion occurs (I'm really sorry `:(`)

Comment: yes please  if it is not problem for you

Answer (score 1):

Consider cutting-up a rectangular solid ("shoebox"). We'll say that the top and bottom faces (each of area $R$) are painted red, the front and back faces (each of area $G$) are painted green, and the left and right faces (each of area $B$) are painted green.

As we slice the box, it helps to think of the pieces sticking together in place in the shape of the original box, rather than thinking that we suddenly have a lot of mini-boxes.

When you slice the shoebox parallel to a pair of faces, you create two unpainted surfaces (one on each side of cut) in the same shape as those painted faces. Those surfaces might get sub-divided by other cuts in other directions, but the *total area* of each surface will always match the area of a painted face.

Thus, a cut parallel to faces of a particular color creates two unpainted surfaces, each with the same area as one of those colored faces. Making $r$ cuts parallel to the red faces, $g$ cuts parallel to the green faces, and $b$ cuts parallel to the blue faces, creates a total unpainted surface area of
$$\text{total unpainted area} \quad = \quad 2 r R + 2 g G + 2 b B \qquad (1)$$

> **Note.** Formula $(1)$ holds no matter where the cuts are made (so long as they're made parallel to the faces). That is, the spacing between cuts is irrelevant.

---

In the case of a $3\times 3 \times 3$ cube, the faces have area
$$R = G = B = 9$$
Cutting this into $27$ sub-cubes involves making $2$ cuts in each direction:
$$r = g = b = 2$$
So, by $(1)$,
$$\text{total unpainted area} \quad = \quad 2\cdot 2 \cdot 9 + 2\cdot 2\cdot 9 + 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 9 \quad = \quad 108$$

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, this not only helped the author but even me. It'll be interesting if the case wether a specific angle of slicing $\theta$ is generalized though.

Comment: i have  edited  my question and my approaches for case of two cube,please see if it is correct

Comment: @Blue we can divide cube into  $a$ part if  volume is  divided into $a$ and we get length ,from which i can take  cubic  root?

Comment: @giorgi: If you have a perfect *clay* cube with side-length $a$ (and volume $a^3$) and slice it into $n$ equal-volume pieces, then you can imagine re-shaping the smaller  pieces of clay into perfect cubes of volume $a^3/n$ and side-length $a/\sqrt[3]{n}$. That's true. However, that's a very different situation than in the classic painted-cube problem, where $n$ is specifically chosen to have a whole-number cube root so that creating perfect sub-cubes is a simple matter of making evenly-spaced cuts in each direction; no "re-shaping" required.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is set for testing one's 3D figure visualization and counting ability.

There are two ways to count the total unpainted area

Method_1

*For the corner blocks,

_There are 8 in total, each has 3 faces unpainted (1 top/bottom + 2 internal faces)

_Sub-total unpainted area = (1 x 1) x 3 x 8 = 24 = p

*For the central block,

_There is only 1, it has 6 (all) faces unpainted

_Subtotal unpainted area = (1 x 1) x 6 = 6 = q

*For the centered block on one face,

_There are 6 in total, it has 5 faces unpainted (1 top/bottom + 4 internal faces)

_Subtotal unpainted area = (1 x 1) x 5 x 6 = 30 = r

*For the remaining not-yet counted (but of the same nature),

_There are 12 in total, it has 4 faces unpainted (1 top/bottom + 3 internal faces)

_Subtotal unpainted area = (1 x 1) x 4 x 12 = 48 = s

Total unpainted area = p + q + r + s = 108

Method_2

Total painted area = 3 x 3 x 6 = 54

If the original was cut before it has been painted, total original surface area = (1 x 1) 6 x 27 = 162

Total unpainted area = 162 - 54 = 108